# How to use CountIf in PBI to count only certain values that fit the criteria in a column

Tags: powerbi, countif

I am trying to create a table in PBI which only counts data based on a certain condition (i.e. Site Status = Completed OR Ongoing) where there are 3 options for site status (Completed, Ongoing and Terminated).

This is the table that I currently have in my PBI report:

[image: Table]

[image: I want this table with the 3rd and 4th column to count sites with a condition]

However, in the 3rd column I want a count of sites with the status 'Ongoing' or 'Completed'. I also want a 4th column where we only count the sites that have 'Terminated' but I am assuming the solution for the 3rd column will closely translate to the solution for the 4th column. To clarify I just want the 3rd and 4th column to count the no of sites which are either Ongoing or Completed, and then only terminated (Per country.)

Any help would be amazing, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ongoing or Completed. Since you're filtering for a string value / constant, you can just do this (instead of using FILTER):

```
   CALCULATE( 
        [Site Count],
         OR(
                   'SiteData'[Site Status]="Completed",
                   'SiteData'[Site Status]="Ongoing"
                   )
    )
```

For "terminated" you'd use the same pattern, but you don't need the OR

```
CALCULATE(
      [Site Count],
      'SiteData'[Site Status]="Terminated"
)
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you for this insight, super useful I appreciate the support. For anyone else that may refer to this in the future I had to go in and change [Site Count] to Count('Name of table'[Name of Column]).

Comment: Only issue is when I try to create the second column it tells me there is a circular dependency even though there is not...

Comment: how you define a Site Count measure will depend on what your fact table looks like. Are you counting rows or are you summing a column (SUM('FactTable'[NumberOfSites])) or are you just counting the records in a table that meet the criteria?  COUNTROWS('Table')?

Comment: I am both counting the rows in the table which meet the criteria, and then summing the values based on those rows. So I have multiple rows per country with different columns of data (as can be seen in the first image); and I want to only sum the 'No of Sites' for the rows that meet the criteria (Sites are Ongoing or Completed) per country. Does this make sense? E.G: for Argentina there are 11 total sites; but only 5 sites that meet the criteria

Comment: Then use 
CALCULATE( 
        SUM([# of Sites]),
         OR(
                   'SiteData'[Site Status]="Completed",
                   'SiteData'[Site Status]="Ongoing"
                   )
    )